# SQL search results by distance

Tags: mysql, database, geocoding, distance

I need some help, I've never done my own SQL search before and I'm trying to do this:

I have a database of names and locations (the locations are listed with a Latitude record and a Longitude record).  Then, a user can search by entering their zip code (which is converted to longitude and latitude) and a distance they're willing to travel (in miles, which I can convert to lon/lat distance).

How can I return the results ordered by the distance away from their ZipCode?

Please keep in mind, I haven't ever done anything like this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mathematical formula for figuring the shortest distance between two points on a sphere.  The formula and a JS implementation of it are here:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

A T-SQL implementation is here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jimjackson/archive/2009/02/13/calculating-distances-between-latitude-and-longitude-t-sql-haversine.aspx

Comment: So once I have all of the locations within the distance desired, how do I display the results ordered from closest to furthest? Is that handled through JavaScript, PHP or SQL?

Comment: I'd do it through SQL - define a database function to calculate the distance and then use that in your select statement:  e.g. "select name, location, zipdistance( userzip, location_lat, location_lon ) as distance from mytable order by zipdistance(userzip, location_lat, location_lon)"